# Move DOM elements when one element resizes using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made gallery which display an image with links (tooltips) on it. When image resizes links should move with position it point on image. Problem is that link move more than it should when image resizes. I can't calculate correct position of links. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            var start_width = $('#inspic').width();
            var start_height = $('#inspic').height();

            $(window).resize(function () {

                var current_width = $('#inspic').width();
                var current_height = $('#inspic').height();

                var change_x = (current_width - start_width);
                var change_y = (current_height - start_height);

                $('.inspiracje_anchor').each(function(i, obj) {

                    var anchor_x = parseInt($(this).css('left'));
                    var anchor_y = parseInt($(this).css('top'));

                    $(this).css('left', (anchor_x + change_x) + 'px');
                    $(this).css('top', (anchor_y + change_y) + 'px');

                    start_width = current_width;
                    start_height = current_height;

                });

            });

        });
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="picture_container">

        <img id="inspic" src="example_image.jpg" />

        <a class="inspiracje_anchor" id="a1" style="left: 453px; top: 250px;">+</a>

        <a class="inspiracje_anchor" id="a2" style="left: 550px; top: 278px;">+</a>

    </div>
```

You can see example here:

[EXAMPLE](http://serwer1749344.home.pl/inspiracje/test.html)

How should i calculate position of links correctly?

Comment: Does it have to be JS? You could position the hotspots absolutely with percentages, then it would always stick to the same position within the image-container.

Comment: it have to be JS, because i create links using offset(); which returns pixel position and i wont rebuild that script.